# Equivalence of module structure involving an $A$-algebra

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, algebras

I'm new to modules and I'm trying to see the following equivalence:

"If $A$ is a commutative ring, $R$ an $A$-algebra (i.e. a ring $R$ with a homomorphism $i : A \rightarrow Z(R)$) and $M$ an Abelian group, giving $M$ an $R$-module structure is equivalent to giving it an $A$-module structure with an $A$-algebra homomorphism $f : R \rightarrow \text{End}_A(M)$."

Now I've seen such a question for the more obvious case where an $R$-module structure is equivalent to a homomorphism $\psi : R \rightarrow \text{End}(M)$. Here it's easy to show that given a module structe $(M, \phi)$ where $\phi : R \times M \rightarrow M$ satisfies the module axioms, you can simply take $\psi : r \mapsto (m \mapsto \phi(r,m))$ and check that this is indeed a homomorphism. Conversely you can define $\phi : (r,m) \mapsto (\psi(r))(m)$ and check that it satisfies the module axioms. I even have a certain 'visualisation' with this. The sentence: "given an $r \in R$, I can make any $m \in M$ into another element of $M$, depending on $r$" seems to describe both cases.

In the current case however, this visualisation is lost on me, and I have no more intuition for what's happening exactly. Let alone proving the equivalence.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: In terms of intuition, think about $A$ as 'the underlying ring of scalars' such as $\mathbb{Z}$ for the case you know, or e.g. a field. Pretty much the same is true here: if $M$ has an $R$-module structure, then it has an $A$-module structure given by $a\cdot m:=i(a)m$. Now for each $r$ the map $f_r(m):= rm$ is $A$-linear: $ f_r(a \cdot m) =f_r(i(a)m)=ri(a)m=i(a)rm=a\cdot rm$; therefore $f_r \in \mathrm{End(A)}$ and check that $f(r):=f_r$ is an $A$-algebra homomorphism. Conversely, given $f:R\rightarrow \mathrm{End}_A(M)$, then the multiplication $r\cdot m:=f(r)m$ satisfies the module axioms.

Comment: Thanks, that cleared up a lot. Two more questions though:
1) The fact that $f : R \rightarrow \text{End}_A(M), r \mapsto f_r$ has to be an "$A$-algebra homomorphism. Does that mean it has to be "$i[A]$-linear" as well als being a ring homomorphism?
2) For "$\Leftarrow$", you actually _need_ the $f : R \rightarrow \text{End}_A(M)$, to make sense of your definition, while for "$\Rightarrow$" it simply "pops up"?

Comment: 1) Yes 

2) Yes, but there's no weird asymmetry or anything like that. I recommend that you look at a specific example. For example, you could identify what each thing is in the following situation: $A=k$, a field; $R=k[x]/(x^2-1)$, the group algebra of the group with 2 elements; $M=k$, with $R$-action given by $1\cdot z=z$ and $x\cdot z=-z$. Do you see how this is the same as specifying the $k$-linear ring homomorphism $f:k[x]/(x^2-1)\rightarrow\mathrm{End}_k(k)=k$ given by $a+bx \mapsto a-b$? What $R$-module action corresponds to $a+bx\mapsto a+b$? Why are these the only two possibilities?

Comment: Thanks for the example, I will get to that later (it's 2:30 here..). About defining, in the converse case, $r \cdot m := f(r)m (= f(r)(m)?)$. It doesn't seem like you're defining it _in terms of_ the $A$-module. Yes, given any ring homomorphism $f : R \rightarrow \text{End}_A(M)$, this definition satisfies the module axioms. However, I never use $A$-multiplication or the $i[A]$-linearity of $f$... (Maybe I'm just too tired)

Comment: The $A$-module structure is necessary since $f(r)\in \mathrm{End}_A(M)$, but indeed you could have chosen any other $A'$-algebra structure for $R$ and $A'$-module structure for $M$, and get the same $R$-module structure for $M$. Again I recommend that you look at specific examples!